# send e-mail with mailx in a bash script waiting if needed for the outcome

Tags: postfix, mailx

I'm writing a bash script that sends an e-mail with attachment to the local user root.

I noticed that `mailx` forks some helper program and terminates instantly with exit status 0 even when the command line arguments are invalid:

```
localhost:~/basinsrv # mailx -s aaa root -a bbb </dev/null ; echo $?; 0
localhost:~/basinsrv # sendmail: invalid option -- 'a'
sendmail: invalid option -- 'a'
sendmail: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]
```

How to make `mailx` wait for the outcome and terminate with proper error code?

Actually, I need to post-process the generated mail before it's sent.

Is it possible to not actually send the message and only save it to a file?

mailx-12.5-31.7.x86_64

postfix-3.6.2-7.1.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution to the error issue is to get the parameters correct in the first place. To fix your example put the recipients at the end of the command line:

```
mailx -s 'subject here' -a 'X-Sent-Using: myscript.sh' root </dev/null
```

But even then it won't wait for `sendmail` (Postfix in your case) as it's not written that way.

And as for post-processing the email, there's no way you can do that. What you'd need to do is to interface directly with `sendmail`. For example something like,

```
from=me@contoso.com             # My email address
to=root                         # Recipient address
(
    echo "From: $from"
    echo "To: $to"
    echo "Subject: it's a fine day"
    echo "X-Sent-Using: ${0##*/}"
    echo
    cat "$message_body_file"    # Let's hope this file exists
) | sendmail "$to"              # May need /usr/sbin/sendmail
```